# How can i have access to my node js application everywhere?

Tags: node.js, listener

I need some explanation. My node JS application is only accessible for me (the network). How can i have make my node js application online ? Do i necessary need to redirect the application via the port 80 ? I need to have access to my application everywhere via the port 8124. http://example.com:8124.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var i;

/**
 * Gestion des requêtes HTTP des utilisateurs en leur renvoyant les fichiers du dossier 'public'
 */
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

/**
 * Lancement du serveur en écoutant les connexions arrivant sur le port 8124
 */
http.listen(8124, function () {
  console.log('Server is listening on *:8124');
});
```

In the function listem, do i have to specify something specific as second parameter ? Also is it safe to let access to people with that type of url ?

Comment: Assuming you're running your server on your home network, then your choices are to run your server elsewhere (like at a hosting company) or to punch a hole in your home network firewall so incoming browser requests can get to your server and set up some sort of DNS solution.  But, this question is probably off-topic for stack overflow.

Comment: My application is hosted in my VPS (hosting company). So not in local. Thanks.

Comment: So you have an application hosted at a hosting company and you want help configuring it and you don't tell us ANYTHING about the hosting company!  Seriously?  You've given us none of the relevant information to help you answer this.  Go read the configuration instructions for your hosting company and then come back and ask a much more specific question.  This question as asked is "too broad" for stack overflow.

Comment: The hosting company is planethoster . I have SSH access , i use forever tu run the node js application. The only issue i have is that only me (the network) can have access to the node js application. I just needed to understand why, what are the reason ? if i type the full nomain name then :8121 it works on my computer (network) but if i try with another internet connexion or any devices it won't work the page annot be displayed.

Comment: So, what part of the hosting company's instructions did you not understand?  Follow their step by step instructions for configuring your app for public access.  Nothing we can do here unless you happen to run into someone who knows your specific hosting company and your specific configuration.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you look into developing on [Cloud9](http://c9.io).  There are no firewall issues to worry about and you can work on your project anywhere and behind any firewall.

If you insist on developing on your own network, then you may want to look into changing your hostname file.  You can map example.com to map to localhost very simply.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My Node JS is hosted via an Hosting Company.  I don't want to develop on my own network. Just make my node js application online for everyone.